# Sound Cloud SSD Group

Tags: discussion

Hi Everyone. I have taken the liberty of starting up a Sound Cloud group for Social Sound Design users. I thought it would be good to have an easy place to listen to each others tracks as we have many of the same sonic interests. It will be interesting to hear how others on this site produce music. The page can be found at [link text](http://soundcloud.com/groups/social-sound-design/tracks) Please feel free to post your tracks up now.

Comment: Great stuff @lenny. Thanks for that :-)

Comment: My bad. Is this solely for Music? What about sound effects we want to share?

Comment: Nice one Lenny!

Comment: No worries, I think it might be best to keep this group for music or soundscape/concrete compositions rather than single sound effects or wild tracks. There is nothing stopping people putting sound effects on their own page and sharing sound effects easily with others if they are using sound cloud.

Comment: agreed Lenny, just joined...

Comment: Awesome! Will be cool to share some stuff.

Comment: Very nice idea :) joined!

Comment: Nice! Joined, with user name Efraim.

Answer (score 3):

I've just added a sidebar widget for our SSD group on SoundCloud :-) Look to the right -->

This way we can listen to each other's Music/SFX/Inspirations... I got a feeling there's a little bit of spam from producers trying to sell their music, but no big deal.

I also added a DropBox, so you can quickly just upload something.

Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

This was such a lovely idea, but it seems to have become flooded with people trying to sell samples.

Seems like a bit of a shame really, as it could be a great place for SSD users to share interesting recordings.

Cheers

Comment: I agree, I wouldn't mind if it were just a few. But the ratio is just wrong. I wonder if I should delete all the ones for sale... 

Comment: I agree, thanks for pointing this out, I have deleted them all as the first page I came across were all for sale and I didn't intend this to be a commercial platform.

Answer (score 2):

Please do not upload commercial tracks on the Sound Cloud SSD group. I didn't mention it when I created the group as I did not expect it would be a problem. Myself and others on the site have had concerns about people using the SSD Sound Cloud page as a commercial platform to sell their tracks or sounds. I hope it doesn't offend anybody but I have deleted all tracks that are for sale. I started up this SC group for members of the SSD community to share sounds and music they have obtained or made and didn't want it being filled up with commercial stuff or people will loose interest in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Great idea. Shared a track I have been working on lately, and checking the other tracks.

Answer (score 0):

I actually added all mine to make a point - I'll remove them - it seems wrong for there to be any sounds with for sale links.... its like advertising....

Comment: Its ok, I have removed all of them Tim so no worries. In hindsight though filling a whole page with samples for sale may not have been the most logical way to make a point about people selling samples on the group page :-)

Comment: Really? I think it made the point perfectly clear.